# Am I wrong here?

Tags: word-usage

Our English teacher told us to frame a sentence using the word lively.

I wrote:

> He was a lively person

But she said it was wrong and couldn't be accepted.

Is she wrong, or am I?

Answer (score 2):

You're correct in the grammatical construction, apart from not having used a full stop at the end of the sentence.

If your intention was to use 'lively' as  an adjective with either of the meanings given in definitions 1 or 2 [here](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/Lively?s=t), you've also conveyed your intended meaning clearly and effectively.

The only remaining difference will be a difference in opinion relating to the truth or falsity of the statement - ie if you were talking about someone acknowledged to be lethargic.

I suggest you ask your teacher to explain their objections to the use in more specific terms.

Comment: Hey, not using full stop was a typo;)

Comment: None of the examples given in Leon's linked article include a human referent used with 'lively'. You'll find an incontrovertible example given by [AHDEL](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/lively). The word is often used with various types of inanimate referents (tune; ball; discussion; breeze; sweeping; time; wit; pink; recollection ...) but animate, including human, referents are by no means wrong (from a language point of view).

Comment: It is also possible that the teacher had asked (or expected) that you write a sentence that shows the meaning of "lively", rather than one in which you just use the word. Or there may have been any other instruction in the question that you missed (which could be as silly as "Write a sentence of at least 25 words in which you use the word 'lively'").  As Leon Conrad points out, you would have to ask your teacher!

Comment: ...And look lively about it.